# Dovecot IMAP action log for a user

Tags: dovecot, thunderbird

I had a strange problem crop up this morning.. one of my users emailed me saying that their email from a the last month had disappeared into their trash. This, unfortunately, is a hostile user.. so it would help smooth things over for everyone if I was able to find out when this occurred. Is there any logging trail that Dovecot has on that would allow me to see this? If not, would Thunderbird have that available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you setup your dovecot **before** the incident. Otherwise dovecot only logs the critical messages. As described in the manual: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging

Thunderbird doesn't log user activity. You can only see logs (of the current session) under Tools->Activities.

Comment: I was not aware of the Tools->Activities option. Thank you for that. Unfortunately Dovecot didn't have the mail_log plugin for IMAP enabled so I guess I'm screwed. Thank you though.